# Java parametric function

Tags: java, function, math

I have to plot something like this:
[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKaB2.gif)

But unfortunately I got
[Already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOtlr.png) and cannot move on.

Could someone tell me what should I put inside my method:

```
private void generateFunction(int num) {
    double step = (2 * Math.PI) / num;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        pointsX.add(i * step);
        pointsY.add(Math.sin(pointsX.get(i)));
        //pointsY2.add(Math.sin(2*pointsX.get(i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is the function you are trying to plot (f(x) = ?)

Comment: @Juan - sin(t) = x(t) sin(2t) = y(t) where t<0,2PI) - it's a parametric function

Comment: If you want x=sin(t) then you should be adding sin(t) to your `pointsX` list.  Right now you're plotting x=t, y=sin(t).

Answer (score 0):

I won't provide the code for doing it, but I'll point you in the right direction.

`t`:  is the parameter and it takes values from `0` to `2 * Pi`

`num`: is the number of plots to cover the `0` to `2 Pi` range.

So `t` will increment in steps of `2 * Pi / num`;

Output grid: X an Y axis will be between -1 and 1 because the `sin()` function will give values in this range.

Your loop will have t as a variable starting from 0 until t is greater than 2*Pi, and you increment t in "step" on each loop.

In each loop you store a pair or coordinates (x,y) in 2 `ArrayLists` as in the example or in 1 `ArraList<Point>` where for each point:
`x = sin(t)` and `y = sin(2t)`

When the the loop is done you have your set of coordinates to plot.